# python keyring download error

Tags: python

I keep getting this error when I try to install a package:

```
Download error on http://keyring-python.org/: (-2, 'Name or service not known') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
Download error on http://home.python-keyring.org/: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution') -- Some packages may not be found!
```

My `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="blah",
    version='0.9dev',
    description="blah",
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'keyring',
        'argparse',
        'Cheetah'
    ],
    entry_points = """
    [console_scripts]
    A = A:main
    """,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither hostname `home.python-keyring.org` nor `keyring-python.org` resolves in DNS.  You need to figure out where the package is hosted and use the correct hostname.

Comment: where do I specify the link in `setup.py` so that the system will look there when it tries to install keyring?